# How to get http call times in c# task.whenall method?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I am running multiple httpclient in tasks.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetRequest(string endpoint, string param)
{
   var client = new HttpClient();
   return client.GetAsync(endpoint+"?p="+param);
}
```

Using this like following

```
public static async Task Start(){
{
    var tasks = new List<HttpResponseMessage>();
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var task = GetRequest("https://address.com",i);
        tasks.Add(task);
    }
    
    var responses = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    
}
```

This sends requests to server. But I want to measure each request duration between send gend get response. How to do this?

Comment: This code does not even compile. In `GetRequest` you already await the task, and in `Start()` you still expect a task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be different approach but the first solution that comes in my mind is to add stopwatch inside the `GetRequest` and return the duration.

```
public async Task<Response> GetRequest(string endpoint, string param)
{
   var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();

   // recommend to use http factory 
   var client = new HttpClient(); 

   stopWatch.Start();        

   // add exception handling if you want to get duration if exception occurs  
   var httpResponseMessage = await client.GetAsync(endpoint+"?p="+param);
   
   stopWatch.Stop();

   return new Response 
   { 
     // Add TimeSpan from stopWatch.Elapsed
     // Add httpResponseMessage or just get the content
   } 
}
```

Tip: It is recommended to use [IHttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) instead of HttpClient directly

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main()
    {
        // Create HttpClient
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

        // List of URLs to make HTTP calls
        string[] urls = { "https://example.com", "https://google.com", "https://stackoverflow.com" };

        // Stopwatch to measure the overall time
        Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        // Create tasks for each HTTP call
        Task[] tasks = new Task[urls.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < urls.Length; i++)
        {
            int index = i; // Capture the current index variable
            tasks[i] = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                Stopwatch httpStopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

                // Make the HTTP call
                HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(urls[index]);

                httpStopwatch.Stop();

                // Print the time taken for the HTTP call
                Console.WriteLine($"HTTP call {index + 1} took {httpStopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
            });
        }

        // Wait for all tasks to complete
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        stopwatch.Stop();

        // Print the overall time taken
        Console.WriteLine($"Overall time: {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this is a nice example. Mainly reusing the httpclient: _HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and re-used throughout the life of an application. Especially in server applications, creating a new HttpClient instance for every request will exhaust the number of sockets available under heavy loads. This will result in SocketException errors._

Answer (score 0):

You can measure the response time by using a stopwatch before and after you do the `client.GetAsync()`. And in `Start()`, you need a list with tasks instead of a list with `HttpResponseMessages`, so you can await these tasks in parallel.

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetRequestMeasured(string endpoint, string param)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();

        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        var response = await client.GetAsync(endpoint + "?p=" + param);

        stopwatch.Stop();

        return response;
    }

    public static async Task Start()
    {
        {
            var tasks = new List<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                var task = GetRequestMeasured("https://address.com", i);
                tasks.Add(task);
            }

            var responses = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        }
    }
```